# System.DirectoryServices.Protocols on Linux Container

Tags: .net, docker, ldap, directoryservices

I am trying to connect to our AD server using System.DirectoryServices.Protocol but it cannot connect. Based on this, it seems to be able to support SSL for Linux Docker container.

But I tried it and receive "The feature is not supported". It throws the error on the .Bind step.

```
using (var connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(server, 636)))
                {
                    var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(login, password, "");
                    connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                    connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;

                    connection.Bind(networkCredential);
                }
```

Am I missing anything? I run same code in my Windows-VisualStudio dev machine, it works correctly.

Do I need to do something special? Maybe install certificate in Linux machine?

Comment: What's the callstack of the exception?

Comment: It was some generic error; Anyway, I have fixed it. It needed Root CA installed in the docker container

Comment: @Water can you describe how you solved it, I am facing the same issue. I want to know how you installed root CA in the docker container, Thanks.